# Is it possible to chose at runtime function that can access private members of a class?

Tags: c++, c++11

The topic might be a it confusing but I believe the concept I am after is pretty easy to grasp.

I have a class, that has some private data. I would like to provide a way to specify a function from the outside of a class that can operate on this data, during the run time. However, I would not like to expose the data to the public.

So far I had something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
    double priv = 0;
public:
    Base(double initial) : priv(initial) {};
    double get_private(){ return priv; };

    static void mix_privates(Base& b1, Base& b2);
};

void Base::mix_privates(Base& b1, Base& b2){
  b1.priv = b2.priv = (b1.priv+b2.priv)/2;
}

//void Base::mix_privates(Base& b1, Base& b2){
//  b1.priv = b2.priv = max(b1.priv, b2.priv);
//}

int main() {
    Base test1(5), test2(10);
    Base::mix_privates( test1, test2 );

    cout << test1.get_private() << '\n';
    cout << test2.get_private() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Up to this point I did not need to change or choose the implementation so I declared the function as a static member, but now I like in the example above I can provide several different implementations of `mix_privates`. Moreover I have many objects similar to `Base` and can easily generalize `mix_privates` for them, for example via template.

Ideally I would like to be able to do is to define few `mix_privates` implementations. For example like this:

```
template<typename BaseLike>
void mix_privates_max(BaseLike& b1, BaseLike& b2){
  b1.priv = b2.priv = max(b1.priv, b2.priv);
}
template<typename BaseLike>
void mix_privates_avg(BaseLike& b1, BaseLike& b2){
  b1.priv = b2.priv = (b1.priv + b2.priv)/2;
}
```

And then in `main` assign a concrete implementation to some general name, e.g:

`std::function<void(Base&, Base&)> mix_privates = mix_privates_avg<Base>`

and then use mixer through general name `mix_privates(test1, test2)` through out rest of the program.

There is no problem if `mix_privates` uses only public members and attributes, and I got it done. But I would like to be able mess with private data. There is also no point in exposing it to public except for this functionality, so I would like to avoid it.

I was thinking about using friendship, but it is not inheritable, which is a drawback, and not transferable, so I think I cannot specify a friend function that would act like a proxy.

Is there a way to implement this or something similar in c++11?

Comment: Is there anything that rules out setters? Something along the line `void Base::set(double a) { priv = a; }`. Is that too much exposition to you?

Comment: Encapsulation is a compile-time feature. There is no concept of public/private/protected at run-time. Why can't you just use `get_private()` and `set_private()` to access the data?

Comment: So you don't want to make it easy to change the private data, but you want to be able to write any number of unrelated functions that can change the private data?

Comment: The real data is more like binary data. I don't want it to be exposed to the whole world. I just ran into a situation where I can generalize and refactor the functions that operate on private data. I think it is a good idea to do it, but I don't think this justifies polluting public API. I want a class of functions to be able to access the private data. For example functors that derive from some `BaseMixer` that would be friend. Or something like this.

Answer (score 3):

What about providing a friend *class* that defines *protected* getter/setter methods? That way only derived classes of the friend can access the internals. E.g.:

```
class Base {
   friend class Access;
   ...
   private: double priv;
};

class Access {
protected:
   double get_private(Base &b) { return b.priv; }
   void set_private(Base &b, double priv) { b.priv = priv; }

public:
   virtual void mix_privates(Base &b1, Base &b2) = 0;
};

class AccessMax : public Access {
    void mix_privates(Base &b1, Base &b2) { set_private(b1, max(get_private(b1), get_private(b2)); }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to the other suggestions, I would consider making `mix_privates` a template that takes a function that will do the actual mix:

```
template <typename Functor>
void Base::mix_privates(Base& b1, Base& b2, Functor f) {
   b1.priv = b2.priv = f(b1,b2);
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
Base b1(..), b2(..);
Base::mix_privates(b1,b2,
                   [](double x, double y) { return (x+y)/2; });  // average
Base::mix_privates(b1,b2,
                   &std::max<double>);                           // max
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `Mixer` class which implements a function `mix(Base& b1, Base& b2)`, and declare an instance of it in `Base`.  Then subclass `Mixer` to implement the various ways to mix.  Assign an instance of your desired `Mixer` subclass to the instance declared in `Base`, and then implement `mix_privates` to call `mix` of the instance.

For example:

```
class Mixer;

class Base{
  double priv = 0;
public:
  ...
  static Mixer* mixer;
  static void mix_privates(Base& b1, Base& b2) {
    mixer->mix(b1, b2);
  };
};

class Mixer {
public:
  void mix(Base& b1, Base&b2) = 0;
};

class MixAverage  : public Mixer {
public:
  void mix(Base& b1, Base&b2) {
    b1.priv = b2.priv = (b1.priv+b2.priv)/2;
  };
}

main {
  ...
  Base b1, b2;
  Base::mixer = new MixAverage();
  ...
  Base::mix_privates(b1, b2);
  ...
}
```

The problems with this is (as pointed out), the `Mixer` and its subclasses cannot access the private members of `Base`.  So, you could make `Mixer` a friend, and implement methods  that can then be used by the subclass to get access to the private member of base.  For example:

```
class Base{
  double priv = 0;
public:
  ...
  static Mixer* mixer;
  static void mix_privates(Base& b1, Base& b2) {
    mixer->mix(b1, b2);
  };
  friend class Mixer;
};

class Mixer {
public:
  void mix(Base& b1, Base&b2) = 0;
  int& priv(Base& b) {
    return b.priv;
  };
};

class MixAverage  : public Mixer {
public:
  void mix(Base& b1, Base&b2) {
    priv(b1) = priv(b2) = (priv(b1)+priv(b2))/2;
  };
}
```

Comment: This won't compile, how does `MixAverage` accesses `Base`'s private members?

Comment: I think it is also possible to skip statics in `Base` and just go `Mixer& mixer = MixAverage(); mixer.mix(b1,b2);` in `main`. I am hella tired but it think it should work. It is a nice idea then.

Comment: The only reason I included it as a static was requirement by OP to be able to use `mix_privates` function...

Comment: Oh, well I am the OP xD, perhaps I didn't make it clear enough that preferably it was to make `mix_privates` `main`-local. It is not a big deal, but it removes quite redundant (to me) lines in `Base` declaration. I think `friend class Access` is enough notion that there will be classes accessing some private data. But thanks for constructing it to match the original "so-far" code. I used `static`, to get access to privates, `friend fuction` would serve same purpose.