# How to expose the implementation only to a specified set of classes in the pimpl idiom?

Tags: c++

Let's have a `class A` which has an inner `class A::Impl`. A `class AllowedToAccess` should be able to get `A::Impl&` from `class A`, no other class should be able to do that or even know that `class A::Impl` exists.

```
class A_1
{
public:
    class Impl;

    Impl& impl();
    const Impl& impl() const;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};

class A_2
{
private:
    friend class AllowedToAccess;

    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};

class A_3
{
private:
    friend class AllowedToAccess;

    class Impl;

    class ImplContainer
    {
        friend class A_3;
        std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl;
    } m_implContainer;

    Impl& impl(); // return *m_implContainer.impl;
    const Impl& impl() const; // return *m_implContainer.impl;
};
```

Here is some code to illustrate my ideas.

**A_1**

Pros: `m_impl` is secured.

Cons: classes not supposed to know about `A::Impl` will know about it (although they don't know what `A::Impl` really is about).

**A_2**

Pros: classes not supposed to know about `A::Impl` will not know about it.

Cons: `m_impl` is not secured (`AllowedToAccess` might just set it to `nullptr`).

**A_3**

Pros: classes not supposed to know about `A::Impl` will not know about it and `m_impl` is secured.

Cons: Boilerplate code for `ImplContainer`.

**Any better ideas?**

EDIT: Came up with a solution like this.

```
template <typename T>
class Accessor
{
private:
    friend class AllowedToAccess;

    typedef typename T::Impl impl_t;

    static typename T::Impl& impl(T& t)
    {
        return *t.m_impl;
    }

    static const typename T::Impl& impl(const T& t)
    {
        return *t.m_impl;
    }
};

class A
{
private:
    friend class Accessor<A>;

    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};

class A::Impl
{
public:
    void f() const
    {

    }
};

class AllowedToAccess
{
public:
    AllowedToAccess()
    {
        const A a;

        const Accessor<A>::impl_t& impl = Accessor<A>::impl(a);

        impl.f();
    }
};
```

There is an implementation layer of code, and all those classes will be added as friends to Accessor.

And to further hide things the accessor would only be forward declared as `template <typename T> class Accessor;` in public code. And defined in private code.

Comment: For `A_2`, if "m_impl is not secured" is your only concern, you can make `m_impl` const, can't you?

Comment: @KirilKirov, unfortunately A has to support moving, so it can't be const. I did not specify that, but let's assume that the solution should not take away any capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if its a better idea, but you could provide your own implementation of `AllowedToAccess`, that would safely expose needed interface. I call it `Accessor`.

```
class Base{
  double priv = 0;
public:
  friend class Accessor;
};

class Accessor {
public:
  int& priv(Base& b) { return b.priv; };
};
```

Now classes can access exposed privates through `Accessor`. The semantics change a bit though because you use it like `accessor.priv(b) = something` but you have full control over the exposed interface. I think `Accessor` in this variation could have all static methods since the accessed object is passed always anyways. So the semantics would be `Accessor::priv(b)`.

I guess it is a variation of your **A_3** example, with code moved into the friend class. But it does not pollute `A_` class.

Another option would be to provide your own `Accessor` class in form of a simple wrapper.

```
class Accessor {
public:
  Accessor(Base b) _b(b);
  int priv() { return _b.priv; };
  int priv(int val) { _b.priv = val; };
  int& priv_r() { return _b.priv; };
private:
  Base& _b;
};
```

The interface here is also fully customizable, and you can access features like:

```
Base b;
Accessor interface(b);
interface.priv(42);
```

You can also make it absolutely safe disallowing to derive from `Accessor` (there are tricks for that), so no-one can derive and screw up your objects via an evil implementation of the `Accessor`. I think it would be a little bit paranoid though.

Comment: This accessor usage gave me a good idea in a bit different way. Take a look at the original question, any comments? Any loopholes?

Comment: @NFRCR Well actually I am not that smart on my own, the idea of Accessor came from the second part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21862539/1133179) to my (similar) question. And the wrapper version is taken from [this guide-article](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/471). I knew you can template 2nd variation of accessor. It is not mine idea, but I actually like it very much. It allows to make/implement arbitrary interfaces, and the friendliness allows to access privates if needed, when it is suitable. I just merged both approaches as it seems suitable in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible to move all logic that works with m_impl itself to a base class, you can make m_impl inaccessible to a derived class, but allow it to get a refernce to `Impl`, and then make `Access` class a friend of a derived class:

```
class Base {
  protected:
    class Impl;
    Impl& impl();
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};

class Base::Impl {
  public: 
    Impl() {}
};

Base::Impl& Base::impl() { return *m_impl; }

class Derived : private Base {
  public:
    friend class Access;
    Derived() { 
      auto& ptr = impl(); // ok
      auto& ptr1 = m_impl; // error
    }
 };

class Access {
  public:
  Access(Derived& d) {
    auto& ptr = d.impl(); // ok
    auto& ptr1 = d.m_impl; // error
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
class A_4
{
public:
    class Impl;

    Impl& impl();
    const Impl& impl() const;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};

class A_4::Impl
{
private:
    friend class A_4;
    friend class AllowedToAccess;

    Impl();
    ~Impl();
    Impl(const Impl&) = delete;
    Impl& operator=(const Impl&) = delete;

    // All members private!
};
```

It doesn't matter that code can call `impl()` or write `A_4::Impl` if there's nothing useful they can actually do with it.

Comment: yes, actually in the case of A_1 that's how A_1::Impl would have looked like. I guess I was just trying to over-secure the implementation. I do have an idea to have some template class Base and move m_impl there (privately), and make it accessible with getters that have protected access. And if A wants to share access to those getters it can declare friends. However, such template code seems quite magical and obscure right now.